# How can I show a flyout in GTK 3?

Tags: python, gtk3

I started creating GTK3 apps in Python a few days ago.
I was wondering how to create a flyout menu like the one gedit shows when Open button is clicked.

Thank you!

[image: Flyout in gedit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [`Gtk.MenuButton`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/MenuButton.html#Gtk.MenuButton) with the `use_popover` property set to `True`.